# ionic nav push params not shown in url

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

**app.module.ts:**

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
        links: [
            { component: CategoryPage, name: 'Category', segment: 'category:id'}
        ]
    }
],
providers: [
    {
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: PathLocationStrategy
    }
]
```

**Configuration of the page I am navigating too**

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'Category',
  segment: 'category/:id'
})
```

**Code which triggers navigation:**

```
this.nav.push(CategoryPage, {id: 3});
```

The component does load as expected and I can call this.navParams.get('id') which yields 3 from within the components class.

**Expected result:** The url changes to /category:3

**Observed result:** The url changes to /category:id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if you are trying to implement deep links for Ionic 3 (since Ionic 4 is using Angular's router by default now) you need to ensure you also configure each page accordingly.

The page you are navigating to needs to have configs added via @IonicPage:

```
@IonicPage({
    segment: 'second/:id'
})
```

See more in [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) or [this guide](https://www.joshmorony.com/link-to-pages-via-urls-with-deep-linking-in-ionic/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have my landing page configured, but I am still getting the same results. I have read through those links, and appreciate you sending them along. I haven't used ionic ion a while and a lot has changed. My project is ionic3.

Comment: Is there any way to debug why it isnt working? This seems like something that is just in the guts of ionic and hard to debug.

Comment: Let me check my working code and i will see whats different

Comment: Something is weird. I just added the same code for my item page and it works. Code I pretty much copy/pasted from the category page.

Comment: found the issue! segment: 'category:id', -> segment: 'category/:id', in app.module.ts

Comment: ouch;) but that makes sense:)